# Why is svn trying to start when I log in? How (or even should) I stop it?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, boot, svn

I upgraded my Tiger install to Snow-leopard last night.

All went fine except every time I start the machine, I'm told that svn requires Rosetta. *I already know what Rosetta is and why I might want to install it. I only mention it because that's the error I'm seeing.*

Now, given that svn isn't in my login-items, does anybody know how to find out why svn is trying to start, and what's using it?

Also, a quick check with Terminal reveals there's an Intel version of svn on the machine already. So is it possible I've ended up with two installs of svn on there? How might I fix that?

It's a 1st gen 2ghz Core Duo Macbook if it makes any odds.

Comment: Got the same deal with Rosetta after installing Snow Leopard.....Can't really understand why either :-S

Comment: Olly - Please in future flag a moderator if you want a question re-opened. I would have happily reopened the previous one. In the meantime I am going to merge these too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having the same issue since installing Snow Leopard, and, thanks to Pierre's suggestion, used Lingon to track the problem down to TextMate's `com.macromates.textmate.bundleupdate` agent, which calls `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Pristine Copy/Bundles/GetBundle.tmbundle/Support/bin/autoupdate.sh`,
which executes `svn` (in the same directory), which is a "Mach-O executable **ppc**".
Using Lingon, I disabled the agent, and now I don't get the message anymore.

I had used System Profiler to find all the PowerPC applications on my machine (but it failed to find this one):
http://www.mactipper.com/2008/06/find-all-your-ppc-applications-system.html

Comment: I thoroughly uninstalled TextMate and reinstalled the latest version, and the offending svn app didn't get reinstalled, so it must have been a vestige from an older version of TextMate.
Besides deleting the TextMate app, I deleted "~/Library/Application Support/TextMate". Don't forget to save your registration info before deleting.

Comment: Hurrah! The textmate bundle was the answer, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Check your login items as well as launchd (using Lingon) to see what is launched when you log in.

SVN is a source code management software.

Answer (score 0):

Snow Leopard already includes an svn client. I suspect that you have installed svn in the old time when Mac OS X didn't include it, possibly before Intel transition.

I don't know what svn would like to do at startup since it is a client. Did you install a svn server as well ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware I've never installed svn (unless it's been installed as part of something else).

Is there a way to track down and remove this copy? It doesn't show up in spotlight and I'm no expert in the Terminal.

I didn't even own a mac prior to the intel transition :)